# 4K (3840x2160) with GeForce GT 730M (Notebook Acer v3-571g) on HDMI port not working

Tags: laptop, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I have a notebook Acer v3-571g with a GeForce GT 730M and try to get my new Samsung UHD Monitor 28" "U28D590D" to work in a 4K resolution via HDMI. The manual of the monitor says it supports 4k via HDMI at 30hz.

The graphic card supports a resolution of 3840x2160, it also is supposed to have a 1.4 HDMI port (http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-730m/specifications), the cable I'm using definitely supports HDMI v. 1.4. 
Maybe the problem is, that it's hybrid card.

```
lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
```

I can't get a 4k resolution to work neither on Windows 8 or Ubuntu 14.10, trying numerous settings and driver versions. The highest resolution I can get is 1920x1080. This is also the highest auto-detected resolution being offered in the gui of display settings in Ubuntu and Windows.

On Windows 8, If I try to manually set the resolution to 4k and 30hz manually in the intel-graphics-tool, I get the message that this bandwith is not supported. Only in interlaced mode I can even set it to those values but it doesn't result i a usable picture. The picture is to small and flickers.

On Ubuntu I tried the following drivers: nvidia-331, nvidia-331-updates, nvidia-346, nvidia-340, nvidia-349, xserver-xorg-video-nouveau.
Together with the following settings:

```
gtf 3840 2160 30
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00" 339.57  3840 4080 4496 5152  2160 2161 2164 2197  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "3840x2160_30.00"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "3840x2160_30.00"
```

Via the nvidia-settings I configured Ubuntu to only use the nvidia graphics card.

**My question is:** 
Is it possible to use this monitor in 4k-resolution with my specific notebook? My research tells me it should, but I can't make it work.

Comment: My Lenovo (so YMMV) has a similar setup. It uses the Intel card for general usage and only switches to the Nvidia for intensive use. This may be of help? http://support.lenovo.com/en/documents/ht078706

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:
I finally found some information on http://www.manualslib.com/manual/440323/Acer-Aspire-V3-571g.html?page=9#manual

```
External resolution / refresh rates:
•VGA port up to 2048 x 1536: 75 Hz
•HDMI port up to 1920 x 1080: 60 Hz
```

so it seems the hardware does not support the resolution, even thought the graphic card and the HDMI port would.

Comment: My Lenovo IdeaPad U430-Touch works with a 4K Monitor, but only at 30Hz